# Spring - AbstractApplicationContext close() method does not destroy bean

Tags: spring

In summary:

a. spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.tutorial.spring" />
</beans>
```

b. SpringJdbcDemo.java

```
package org.tutorial.spring;

import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.tutorial.spring.dao.SpringJdbcDao;
import org.tutorial.spring.model.Circle;

public class SpringJdbcDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    AbstractApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
    SpringJdbcDao dao = ctx.getBean("springJdbcDao", SpringJdbcDao.class);
    ctx.close();
    Circle circle = dao.getCircle(1);
    System.out.println(circle);
}

}
```

Notice that the ctx.close() is before the dao.getCircle();

c. SpringJdbcDao.java

```
package org.tutorial.spring.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.tutorial.spring.model.Circle;

@Component
public class SpringJdbcDao {

public Circle getCircle(int circleId) {

    Connection conn = null;
    Circle circle = null;
    String derbyDriver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver";

    try {
        Class.forName(derbyDriver).newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/db");
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select * from circle");
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) {
            circle = new Circle(circleId, rs.getString("name"));
        }

        rs.close();
        ps.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e.toString());
    } finally {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return circle;
}

}
```

The output:

Feb 24, 2013 9:40:55 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@45e7c8de: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,springJdbcDao,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
Circle [id=1, name=First Circle

The dao still works after the ctx.close() method.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The dao still works after the ctx.close() method.

Why would it not work? Once you have an instance of your `SpringJdbcDao`, it doesn't require any help from Spring to do its work. With the above, you've basically written a really complicated version of `SpringJdbcDao dao = new SpringJdbcDao()`.

Comment: @ryansteward As stipulated in the close method API, the close method should destroy any bean in the bean factory. Destroy meaning removing it from service. As shown in the log INFO: Destroying singletons .. i expect the close method to put SpringJdbcDao object out of service. Isn't that the meaning of DESTROY?

Comment: True. The bean is no longer available for use within the ApplicationContext; however, the code in your main method isn't in an ApplicationContext, and it still has a reference to an instance of your class, which works just fine without Spring.

Comment: @ryansteward ApplicationContext is to provide bean for client - which in my case is SpringJdbcDemo - which is true - not within the ApplicationContext. Based on your comment, how does a bean get destroyed and not being able to be used within the ApplicationContext?

Comment: I'm not even sure how to answer this... Spring isn't magic. All it does is call constructors and set properties, just like you might do in your own code. The fact that you close a Spring context doesn't mean that all the objects it created are suddenly gone or invalid. The only effect you'd see when Spring "destroys" a bean is that an object's [appropriate "destroy method"](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-nature) would be called. You haven't defined any, so nothing happens.

Comment: i still don't understand. Just like a servlet object, when we talk about the destruction of a servlet object, that object is completely destroyed and out of service. That is in simplicity the concept of destruction of an object. In spring bean case, it is the spring bean object. If that is not the semantic meaning of a bean destruction then what is the exact semantic when we talk about the destruction of a spring bean object? Bear in mind there is only 1 spring bean SpringJdbcDao object - singleton.

Comment: Not so. Imagine if you defined a method on a servlet that simply added two numbers together and then obtained a reference to that servlet object from a container. After you shut down the container, thus "destroying" the servlet, you still have the reference, and you could still call that method and get a correct result because it, like a bean, is just an object. That's effectively what you're doing in your example, except it's a Spring bean and Spring container instead of a Servlet and Servlet container.

Comment: If the servlet container goes down the servlet object is gone. Kaput. There is no longer that object. That is where garbage collection comes in. That memory allocation is reclaimed hence wiping out that object. You cannot refer to that object anymore cos' it is gone. If not i don't see the purpose of an object being destroyed and yet still can be referenced by client.

Comment: No, that's incorrect. Garbage collection isn't synonymous with "destroying" either a servlet or a bean. By definition, if you obtain a reference to something and hold it, that object *can't* be garbage-collected.

Comment: I do understand that. Then what's the purpose of a destruction of a spring bean? I just need the semantic of it. What is the exact semantic of a bean destruction? What role does it play in a bean?

Comment: Did you read my second comment? When a bean is destroyed, it's "destroy method" is called. You've defined no such method, so nothing happens. The link there describes bean lifecycle, including the ways you can define a destroy method. Here it is again: [http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-nature](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-nature).

Comment: I know that the destroy method is called before the bean is destroyed. This destroy method could be used for anything prior to bean destruction. So what. Lets say i put a system.out.println() in this method. So? After this method is called then what happen? What will happen to the bean? The destroy method is just a method being called prior to bean destruction. Tell me what will happen to the bean after this destroy method is called. I still don't have a clear semantic when it comes to bean destruction.

Comment: If you don't hold on to a reference to it yourself, it'll probably be garbage collected eventually. That's it. Nothing else.

Comment: So what you are saying is that the close() method does not really force the object to being not being able to be referenced - meaning force any reference to this object to be null now. Seems that way.

Comment: What you're suggesting is impossible in Java. Again, Spring isn't magic.